# Unable to place a div element using bottom zero

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a chat box using bootstrap css version 3 like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="chatBox">
    <div class="row" id="chatHeader">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">Chat bot</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="chatContent">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <!--CONTENT HERE-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="chatFooter" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <textarea rows="1" class="form-control" rows="3" style="resize:none; white-space: nowrap; border-radius: 0px;"></textarea>
                <span id="send_chat" class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary" style="background: #357ebd">Send</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">Send</div>-->
    </div>
</div>
```

style:

```
#chatBox{
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 1001;
    box-shadow: 3px 5px 20px #888888;
}

#chatHeader{
    padding: 10px;
    background: green;
    color: white;
}

#chatContent{
    height: 250px;
    background: white;
}

#chatFooter{
    background: white;
}
```

The last row where the footer div is hidden behind the browser (I mean I had to using `bottom: 25px;` to make it appear properly)

Why is it like that? Here is the plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/v0X8lSL84oNd5KNZT0TV?p=preview

Update:

Not setting the height of `chatBox` fixed the issue. But other problem is I am unable to dynamically set the height of div. Please check this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/v0X8lSL84oNd5KNZT0TV?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set the height of the `#chatBox` (you overflowing it currently), but if you need it to be exactly `300px` as you set, play with `#chatContent` and make it flexible height for example.

Comment: I am trying that currently.

Comment: One more issue is I am able to dynamically set height of div. Please check the updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/v0X8lSL84oNd5KNZT0TV?p=preview

Comment: Could you please be more specific what is an issue now?

Comment: I want to add/remove classes dynamically for `chatContent`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/OIqhAQhbjOAAlu0lpSMb?p=preview, .toggle() is jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reasons is that you have a `padding` set to your header. The padding is pushing everything under it down. I guess the best option is to set the `bottom` to `25px`. This will do no damage as far I can see.